# Accessing E4X nodes having special characters in name without breaking binding chain in flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, binding, e4x

I am using E4X to bind some values from xml in flex 3.

There is a problem when xml tag's (or attribute's) name has special character in it: having xml content

```
var xml:XML = <tag>
    <special-name att="val" />
</tag>
```

`special-name` could not be accessed using `xml.special-name.@att` because it is interpreted as subtraction, on the other hand using square bracket notation `xml['special-name'].@att` breaks binding chain.

Is there an elegant way to solve this (like special language syntax) without writing custom binding setters and listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the `child()` function of the [`XML`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/XML.html) class work for you in that situation? I can't check it right now, but `child()` returns an `XMLList` and that should work for binding.

Alternatively, couldn't you just replace all "problematic" node names (storing the original names in a Dictionary with the replacement names being the keys) and then do the binding, simply avoiding the issue altogether?

Comment: Actually, calling child() will break binding, because binding only works with properties (as opposed to method calls). However, using child() will make compiler happy (removes warnings) for not using bracket notation.

I don't fully understand how are you suggesting to replace names?

Comment: If the XML wasn't too large, you could use String manipulation to replace the problematic names with ones that do work. I know that you generally should not be doing String manipulation on XML (don't beat me please ^^), but that could help you out. I suggested storing the replaced names so that you could switch them back in case you'd need to store/send the XML to a server after using it.

Comment: I guess I'm not that desperate about this to even perform string replacing.. because it's not trivial to replace tag names excluding any accidental occurrence in the content.